# Modifying word separators per scope

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, tmlanguage

I have a custom .tmLanguage file on Sublime Text that require certain word separators. Can I change the word separator per scope inside the same language?

I can change the separators using the .sublime-settings file, but it changes to the entire file.

*Example:*
On my language I have a special scope that contains all element inside a double square brackets ("[[ content ]]"). Inside that scope I need the char "/" to NOT be a word separator but I do want it on the rest of the file.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works but there are language specific settings files like `php.sublime-settings`. I didn't try if these are applied to the whole file or only to the parts of the file containing that specific language but it could be worth a try.

Comment: Well, i tried extracting my scope into another tmLanguage file and set its own sublime-settings file, but it seems like sublime will choose the settings defined on the main current language (and not the one that's defined on the scope), when the same settings is in existence.